# how to make angular table with sticky header stick to an offset

Tags: angular

I have the following working example of an angular table with a sticky header:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h1utvg?file=app/table-sticky-header-example.css

My question is: how to prevent the table from going all the way up to the top, when scrolling, but stop at an offset.
I've tried something like:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 30px;
}
```

But that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correct understand your question - you could just override `top` property for `.mat-table-sticky` class:

```
::ng-deep .mat-table-sticky {
  top: 30px !important;
}
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h1utvg-kjdh15?file=app%2Ftable-sticky-header-example.css).