# how to make table header inside mat-sidenav-container sticky

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a solution here how to make angular table header sticky:
[how to make angular table with sticky header stick to an offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69572203/how-to-make-angular-table-with-sticky-header-stick-to-an-offset/69573379#69573379)

My next question is how to make it stick while inside mat-sidenav-container. Wrapping the table inside mat-sidenav-container doesn't work:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h1utvg-zpqlsa?file=app%2Ftable-sticky-header-example.html

I can see that mat-sidenav-container and mat-sidenav content set the position to relative. I've tried manipulating the position property to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap `table` with some `container` and set some `max-height` to it. See [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h1utvg-yvn86q?file=app%2Ftable-sticky-header-example.css).

Comment: So there isn't a way to accomplish this without limiting the table height?